# I encountered this error in android studio while learning it

Tags: android

I encountered this error in android studio while learning it:

> 08-20 11:56:52.192 9815-9815/com.example.android.courtcountee1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.android.courtcountee1, PID: 9815
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.courtcountee1/com.example.android.courtcountee1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #66: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #66: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>                                                                                        at com.example.android.courtcountee1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
>                                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
>                                                                                        at com.example.android.courtcountee1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

The XML

i THINK THE VIEW TAG IS CAUSING THE PROBLEM AS REMOVING IT RESOLVED THIS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context="com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Team A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="threePoints"
                android:text="+3 POINTS" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="twoPoints"
                android:text="+2 POINTS" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="freeThrow"
                android:text="Free Throw" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--<view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
        </view>-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Team B"
                android:textColor="#616161"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="56dp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="threePointsB"
                android:text="+3 POINTS" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="twoPointsB"
                android:text="+2 POINTS" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:onClick="freeThrowB"
                android:text="Free Throw" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:text="RESET" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: post your MainActivity XML and tell me

Comment: It already show your layout xml 8 no line have problem.

Comment: This happens when i try to run this app on an android device

Comment: I found the culprit as adding the view tag resulted in error and commenting it out cleared the error. But why is the view tag causing this error

Answer (score 0):

View tag must start with the capital letter, like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact,Every xml View tag will through the `LayoutInflater` class construct a real View class. About `LayoutInflater`, It will combine the xml tag with the View class in package `android.view.`、`android.widget`、`android.webkit`、`android.app`. About you use the `view` tag, you should use like this.

```
    <view
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    class="androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    />
```

you must appoint the target class. because the `LayoutInflater` tell us should do.

```
    View createViewFromTag(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        boolean ignoreThemeAttr) {
    if (name.equals("view")) {
        name = attrs.getAttributeValue(null, "class");
    }

    // Apply a theme wrapper, if allowed and one is specified.
    if (!ignoreThemeAttr) {
        final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS_THEME);
        final int themeResId = ta.getResourceId(0, 0);
        if (themeResId != 0) {
            context = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, themeResId);
        }
        ta.recycle();
    }

    if (name.equals(TAG_1995)) {
        // Let's party like it's 1995!
        return new BlinkLayout(context, attrs);
    }
    ...
```

because you not appoint the class.It can not find the real class about it,So It cause the exception.